# How do I package a node web-kit app for publishing in mac app store?

Tags: macos, package, node-webkit, software-distribution, mac-app-store

I've searched a bit but can't find an existing tool for this.

how to package node web-kit project for mac osx and what steps to follow to distribute this app to mac app store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have a look at the Node-webkit generator for Yeoman:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-node-webkit

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-node-webkit
$ yo node-webkit
```

This will give you a folder with a set of tools to package and test your app for Windows, Mac and Linux. 
Put your code on the **app** folder and run

```
grunt dist-mac
```

Next, sign up for a developer account at apple https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/

And once you're done, grab your app from the **dist** folder and submit it to Apple.
The submission process may vary from the one for iOS, but you can find all the information on the Mac Dev Center.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

1. Download webkit last  version  from : 
   https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit#downloads
2. create new Folder for you Application
3. put you HTML5 and Javascript  Application in Side new Folder
4. create  Application Manifest Format "package.json" with following
   Docmentaction :
   https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format
5. install  "Node  webkit  Builder "  -->   npm install node-webkit-builder -g
6. use Build to Get Application application for  Paltform :

   Usage: nwbuild [options] [path]

   Options:
     -p, --platforms      Platforms to build, comma-sperated, can be: win32,win64,osx32,osx64,linux32,linux64   ['osx32', 'osx64', 'win32', 'win64']
     -v, --version        The nw version, eg. 0.8.4                                [default: "latest"]
     -r, --run            Runs node-webkit for the current platform                [default: false]
     -o, --buildDir       The build folder                                         [default: "./build"]
     -f, --forceDownload  Force download of node-webkit                            [default: false]
     --quiet              Disables logging                                         [default: false]

Comment: I get the following error when I tried this: `Error: Invalid protocol: null`